# as.Date function not working for year only

Tags: date, shiny, character, as.date

I'm trying to convert a column called "year" in the Palmerpenguins dataset to a date using as.Date but it is NOT working. I need to convert from characters to date for a shiny app I'm trying to develop.

The code I used was:
pyear <- as.Date(penguins$year, format = "%Y")

but when I run typeof(pyear) it returns "double"

[as.Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUegJ.png)

[Shiny app layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiDyK.png)

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/04/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-handling-date-time-in-r/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` in R comes with year, month, day (not necessarily in this order). If you really wish to keep the `year` column as `Date`, I think you need placeholders where you can ignore.

`as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(penguins$year))` will produce `Date` objects like `"2007-01-01"`. You may later use `lubridate::year(as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(penguins$year)))` to extract years.